# Solve Matrix equation AXB+C=D

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have 4 known matrices:

1. mA = 4x4 -> `{{-4, 1, 5, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 17, 0, 1}}`
2. mB = 3x3 -> `{{-4, 7, 10}, {2, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}`
3. mC = 4x3 -> `{{1, 2, 2}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}`
4. mD = 4x3 -> `{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -1}}`

And one unknown:

1. X = 4x3

I want to solve an equation for X in the form `mA.X.B+C=D`. How can I do this in mathematica? I'm brand new to this language. =)

[EDIT]
What I tried and my thought process:

1. AXB+C=D -> AXB = D-C -> D-C=E
2. AXB=E
3. A^-1x(AXB)=A^-1xE
4. I(XB)=A^-1xE
5. XB=A^-1xE

```
matrixE = matrixD-MatrixC
invA = Inverse[matrixA]

right_equation = invA.matrixE
LinearSolve[matrixB, right_equation]
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and display it along with your matrices in Mathematica format.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo; x is 4x3. I'll update with what I've tried.

Comment: `mX = Array[x, {4, 3}];
solution = mX /. First[Solve[(mA . mX . mB + mC) == mD]]`

Comment: The mX statement creates a 4x3 matrix. But what happens afterwards?

Comment: @OLGJ `Solve` finds the solution(s) and returns lists of lists of rules mapping x[i,j] to some number - in this case there's only one list of rules so we take the `First`. The `mX /.` then takes the `mX` array of x[i,j] variables and applies those rules leaving you with just a 4x3 matrix of numbers.

Comment: Thanks @flinty! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mA = {{-4, 1, 5, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 17, 0, 1}};
mB = {{-4, 7, 10}, {2, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
mC = {{1, 2, 2}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
mD = {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -1}};

mX = Inverse[mA] . (mD - mC) . Inverse[mB]
(*    {{-4/7, -141/35, 202/35},
       {0,    1/35,    -2/35},
       {-3/7, -106/35, 152/35},
       {3/7,  89/35,   -118/35}}    *)
```

test:

```
mA . mX . mB + mC == mD
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: I was not aware you could multiply with the inverse of both matrix a & b. But your explanation of it makes sense. Thank you very much Roman!

Comment: The trick that is so trivial that we keep forgetting it is that LEFT and RIGHT inverses are the same: `mA . Inverse[mA] == Inverse[mA] . mA == IdentityMatrix[4]`. [See here for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Answer (score 5):

`LyapunovSolve` can be used:

```
zeros = SparseArray[{}, #] &; (* create array of zeros *)
mA = {{-4, 1, 5, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 17, 0, 1}};
mB = {{-4, 7, 10}, {2, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}};
mC = {{1, 2, 2}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
mD = {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -1}};

mX = LyapunovSolve[{mA, zeros[{4, 4}]}, {zeros[{3, 3}], mB}, mD - mC]
(*
{{-(4/7), -(141/35),  202/35},
 {  0,        1/35,   -(2/35)},
 {-(3/7), -(106/35),  152/35},
 {  3/7,     89/35, -(118/35)}}
*)

mA . mX . mB + mC == mD
(*  True  *)
```

*Update: Alternative*

```
mX = LinearSolve[mA, 
 Transpose@LinearSolve[Transpose@mB, Transpose[mD - mC]]]
```

Comment: I have not encountered Lyapunov's method before, but it seems to do the job. Thanks for taking the time Michael!